# Fail to set input and output in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am doing a prolog practice which is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287919/goldbach-s-conjecture-in-prolog).

What I want to do now is to change the input and output way of the program.
I need to execute the program by typing this in the console:

```
goldbach(100, L).
```

just for example, and I need to press [;] to show next result when previous one is printed on the screen.

```
L = [3, 97];
L = [11, 89];
L = ....
```

However, what I want to make is like below:

```
Input a number:100.
L = [3, 97].
L = [11, 89].
.....
```

That is the program will print "Input a number:" first and read your input, then automatically print out all possible result.

I have read sections about read() and write, but I get fail when I add these:

```
read_gold :-
  write('Input a number:'),
  read(X),
  write(goldbach(X, L)).
```

How can I fix my code to make the program to achieve the input and output that I want? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You want to modify or reimplement the toplevel. Definitely, too complex for a beginner.

Comment: You can't `write(goldbach(X, L))` to get the results of querying `goldbach(X, L)`. Predicates don't return solutions as functions return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do literally what you're asking for, although it's not normally how one uses Prolog queries and solutions.

```
read_gold :-
  write('Input a number:'),
  read(X),
  show_results(goldbach(X)).

show_results(Query) :-
  call(Query, L),
  write('L = '), write(L), write('.'), nl,
  fail.
show_results(_).
```

A cleaner way to collect all of the solutions in one go is to list them using `findall/3`:

```
read_gold(Solutions) :-
  write('Input a number:'),
  read(X),
  findall(L, goldbach(X, L), Solutions).
```

Or, without explicitly prompting:

```
read_gold(X, Solutions) :-
  findall(L, goldbach(X, L), Solutions).
```

And query it as, for example:

```
?- read_gold(100, Solutions).
Solutions = [[3, 97], [11,89], ...]
```

Comment: Using`write/1` for writing terms is quite problematic. Rather use `writeq/1`

Comment: Thanks for your answering. Now I know that I should read about query. It is a good and important thing to solve most of the problems.